# React callback after re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, state, ipc

I am building an app using React and Electron.

Once a button is pressed, I want to take a screenshot of the browser window. I first update state to close the 'save screenshot' modal, then in the callback of `this.setState`, I send an `ipcRenderer` event, which causes Electron to take a screenshot.

However, my screenshots still have the modal visible. I assume this occurs because, although React has updated state, it has not actually drawn the updated component to the screen.

Is there any way I can call a function only when I know React has updates what the user actually sees?

Relevant code inside App.js:

```
this.setState({screenshotError: "", open:""}, () => {
    ipcRenderer.send('takeScreenshot', {name: this.state.screenshotFieldVal});
})
```

Comment: You can use `componentDidUpdate` function